# How to Enable MultiDex Support in Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I face on compile error "com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536", I search in google the problem is my project reached a limit of method.  I following from [MultIDex](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) instruction.  I added build.gradle, the following is file context of build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 15
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 15 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 21

         // Enabling multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled = true
     }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

When I build it again, the error still exist, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You will need also to create a custom application and override the attachBaseContext method as follow:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {


    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

then add it on your manifest as follow:

```
 <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
   .....
 </application>
```

and voila!

Comment: I already added " <application android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" to AndroidManifext.xml or I must create self application?

Comment: can you just create your application and override attachBaseContext or onCreate method? although it should be the same thing as the MultiDexApplication

Comment: I created MyApplication and overrided attachBaseContext method, the error still exist.  My question is the build.gradle must execute in Intellij IDEA without another config?

Comment: Yes, <application android:name=".MyApplication", but the error still exist

Answer (score 0):

I have what other responders have suggested but IntelliJ still doesn't recognize the MultiDex package, even with the library added manually to the project (`multidex-1.0.1.aar` file, as pulled in by Gradle). The real issue is that IntelliJ doesn't seem to recognize symbols in `aar` files yet. However, the app still builds via a Gradle task in IntelliJ.